# How to use a variable with Order by clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting

I have a variable which contains sort information like below. The sorting information can vary according to columns that's why I have saved it in a variable.

```
Declare @Sorting varchar(100) = 'AssetCode asc'
```

I'm using this variable for sorting with following query, but it's not sorting the data according to the sorting details.

```
with _result as         
(        
    select        
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by @Sorting) as RowIndex,        
        *         
    from 
        @Assets        
    where 
        (@Keyword is null or (AssetCode like @Keyword         
                              or DisplayName like @Keyword        
                              or CategoryName like @Keyword        
                              or SiteName like @Keyword        
                              or BldgName like @Keyword        
                              or SuiteName like @Keyword        
                              or Location like @Keyword  
                              or SerialVIN like @Keyword    
                              or Barcode like @Keyword))       
        )
```

Can anyone please tell me that how I can use this variable with the query to sort the result? I'll be really thankful.

Comment: Make it as dynamically sql ... make @sql nvarchar(max) ... put whole query in it with order by variable ... and go with execute (@sql) and youll get what you want

Comment: Create your query as table view function and then use dynamic sql with the execute command.

Comment: @Veljko89 Isn't there any short way for this?

Comment: Not really, no ...

Comment: In general, I would suggest eliminating all this OR's with concating (+)  '-' +col1 + '-' +col2 +... like '-' + @keyword + '-'

Comment: @sagi: the OP is using SQL Server **2008**, and the `CONCAT` keyword is a new feature in SQL Server **2012** - so he really cannot use that ....

Comment: @marc_s Is there any short way to achieve what I'm trying to do. I don't want to concat the whole query in a variable to execute it.

Comment: @marc_s My mistake, updated the comment.

Comment: @CodeRider You've had that question answered - no, there is not a way to dynamically specify columns in SQL, either in the `Order By` or in the `Select`.  If you want more dynamic ordering you may find it easier to do in the application/reporting layer.  Dynamic SQL also hides any syntax errors until runtime.

Comment: @Veljko89: Why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: I'm here to help out and learn when i can and if I can ... I don't really care for points. Also, I noticed you using 'select * from @Assets', you using table variable ... better check out for temporary tables, they are faster for usage, avoid using table variables, that's just my opinion

Comment: If you want to help out then providing an answer is the best way to do that, because when people have this same issue in the future and end up here it's easier for them to check a selected answer then it is to read through a bunch of comments hoping to find an answer.

Comment: I stand myself corrected ... you are right @TomH ... I shall do that in future

Answer (score 4):

Alternative way which doesn't use dynamic SQL:

```
-- order by flags, 1 = ASC, 0 = DESC, NULL = not order by this.
Declare @SortingByAssetCode bit = NULL;
Declare @SortingByDisplayName bit = 1;
Declare @SortingByCategoryName bit = NULL;
....

SELECT ...
...
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN SortingByAssetCode = 1 THEN AssetCode ELSE 0 END ASC,
  CASE WHEN SortingByAssetCode = 0 THEN AssetCode ELSE 0 END DESC,
  CASE WHEN SortingByDisplayName = 1 THEN DisplayName ELSE 0 END ASC,
  CASE WHEN SortingByDisplayName = 0 THEN DisplayName ELSE 0 END DESC,
  ...
```

You cannot dynamically change the order of the fields (like order by display name first, asset code afterwards).

Most probably it is really really slow and really really hard to maintain.

Comment: The process you have defined, does it make any effect on performance?

Comment: I guess yes: I doubt that the DBMS can use any indexes when the fields are in `CASE WHEN` constructs. It depends on how important indexes on the order by fields are in the specific case. And of course it needs to evaluate the `CASE` statement for each returned row, and it always orders by many expressions even though most of them return 0.

Comment: The only issue with this is that you have to use an actual column name, not an alias (ie dbo.pay_Date AS [pDate]). Not a big deal unless performing an operation in the SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without dynamic SQL using a simple `CASE` statement. You might want to adjust your variable to use a separate 'ASC'/'DESC' variable, although you could parse your existing variable in a pinch.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
                           CASE WHEN @order = 'DESC' THEN
                               CASE @Sorting
                                   WHEN 'customer_id' THEN RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 20) + CAST(customer_id AS VARCHAR(20)), 20)
                                   WHEN 'first_name' THEN first_name
                                   ... etc.
                                   ELSE NULL
                               END
                               ELSE NULL
                           END DESC,
                           CASE WHEN @order = 'DESC' THEN
                               CASE @Sorting
                                   WHEN 'customer_id' THEN RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 20) + CAST(customer_id AS VARCHAR(20)), 20)
                                   WHEN 'first_name' THEN first_name
                                   ... etc.
                                   ELSE NULL
                               END
                               ELSE NULL
                           END ASC
) as RowIndex,
    *
FROM
    @Assets
WHERE
```

Notice how the `customer_id` has to be massaged into a string that will sort correctly **as a string**. You would need to do the same for dates, etc. as all of the datatypes must match. A string is something that all datatypes can be coerced into (although technically I should have probable used `NVARCHAR`).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass in a variable like that, you will need to use multiple case statement.  Given the structure of your variable:

```
row_number() over ((case when @sorting = 'AssetCode asc' then AssetCode end) asc,
                   (case when @sorting = 'AssetCode desc' then AssetCode end) desc,
                   . . .
                  )
```

You should be able to add enough of these expressions for your purposes.  The key is the lack of `else` clause.  This defaults to `NULL`, so mismatches all have the same value.  I see no reason to separate the `asc`/`desc` into a separate variable.

And, another alternative is dynamic SQL.  Dynamic SQL has the advantage that the optimizer can then use an index for the `row_number()` calculation.